# Music streaming service for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, audio-player

I am working on making an iphone music app. I am wondering from where does apps like Songza, Pandora get their Music Stream from and How can I implement such music stream in my app. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a pretty tall order. I'm pretty sure those services built their own streaming services from the ground up. Are you looking to be able to access their APIs and stream from their services, or are you asking specifically about the technical issues behind the music/data streaming?

Comment: Thanks Boztalay for writing. I am more interested in technical issues behind the music/data streaming. if you could tell me a bit more about that, It will be great. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in HTTP streaming then take a look at the [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) Resources from Apple.

There is a sample project on GitHub for a streaming audio player [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607333/ios-streaming-audio-player).